# ember + ember-data 1.13.5 - infinite initialize loop

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I updated ember + ember-data version of existing project using [these instructions](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases), and I'm getting an infinite loop inside ember-data init process.

ember versions:

```
ember-cli: 1.13.1
ember-data: 1.13.5
ember: 1.13.3
```

the package.json and bower.json is what I got from ember-cli + some packages I installed. the inifinite loop I get is this (stack trace from chrome):

```
.......
ember$data$lib$system$container$proxy$$ContainerProxy.aliasedFactory.create (container-proxy.js:22)
instantiate (ember.debug.js:1446)
lookup (ember.debug.js:1313)
buildInjections (ember.debug.js:1344)
injectionsFor (ember.debug.js:1396)
factoryFor (ember.debug.js:1373)
instantiate (ember.debug.js:1415)
lookup (ember.debug.js:1313)
Container.lookup (ember.debug.js:1245)
Registry.lookup (ember.debug.js:1666)

ember$data$lib$system$container$proxy$$ContainerProxy.aliasedFactory.create (container-proxy.js:22)
instantiate (ember.debug.js:1446)
lookup (ember.debug.js:1313)
buildInjections (ember.debug.js:1344)
injectionsFor (ember.debug.js:1396)
factoryFor (ember.debug.js:1373)
instantiate (ember.debug.js:1415)
lookup (ember.debug.js:1313)
Container.lookup (ember.debug.js:1245)

ember$data$lib$instance$initializers$initialize$store$service$$initializeStoreService (initialize-store-service.js:33)
    (anonymous function) (ember.debug.js:4356)
(anonymous function) (ember.debug.js:4372)
visit (ember.debug.js:2241)
DAG.topsort (ember.debug.js:2352)
_emberRuntimeSystemNamespace.default.extend._runInitializer (ember.debug.js:4371)
_emberRuntimeSystemNamespace.default.extend.runInstanceInitializers (ember.debug.js:4354)
_emberRuntimeSystemNamespace.default.extend.didBecomeReady (ember.debug.js:4386)
Queue.invoke (ember.debug.js:903)
Queue.flush (ember.debug.js:967)
DeferredActionQueues.flush (ember.debug.js:767)
Backburner.end (ember.debug.js:160)
Backburner.run (ember.debug.js:228)
Backburner.join (ember.debug.js:263)
run.join (ember.debug.js:19526)
run.bind (ember.debug.js:19589)
jQuery.Callbacks.fire (jquery.js:3148)
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith (jquery.js:3260)
jQuery.extend.ready (jquery.js:3472)
completed (jquery.js:3503)
```

the lookup-and-aliasedFactory.create() part repeat infinitely, with "store:main" instantiate "srvice:store" and "service:store" instantiate "store:main" from its init.

more specifically, the loop comes from the function initializeStoreService() (in file "initialize-store-service.js"), that runs  container.lookup('service:store');

This invoke the 'service:store' instantiate, which at ember-debug.js calls "hash[injection.property] = lookup(container, injection.fullName);" with fullName being "store:main"... since store:main hasn't finish its init, this tries to instantiate "store:main" again which cause the infinite loop.

Is this a bug in ember? How do I fix it?

Thanks!

UPDATE: 
apparently this happens if I do:

```
application.inject('service', 'store', 'store:main');
```

inside an initializer. is this illegal?

Comment: Which version of Ember itself?

Comment: @Kingpin2k 1.13.3, added to question. also notice to update it happens when I call application.inject('service', 'store', 'store:main'); in an initializer. thanks

Comment: That's why, the store itself is a service now, please include the relevant code where you are doing this.  That looks like an old initializer, and not an instance initializer.

Comment: @Kingpin2k yeah I was using an old initializer (exported a native dictionary instead of using an instance initializer / initializer), but anyway I found I can remove the application.inject() and everything works.  thanks :)